# Taking the limit of a undefined derivative

Tags: calculus

[image]

For the following function, the     $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ is said to be equal to $\frac{1}{e^2}$; however, whenever I take the derivative, the derivative, it is undefined, so how can we get a value such as $\frac{1}{e^2}$? If I take the product rule for derivatives and take the limit of the natural log it gives me 1 and not -2 for the exponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derivatives in limits are generally used for L'Hôpital's rule. In this case it is not possible. You simply take the limit of such expression and get the result $\frac{1}{e^2}$. This is because if you expand such expression you get the limit of $e^{2nln(1-\frac{1}{n})}$ which gets you $e^{-2} = \frac{1}{e^2}$. This results in:

$\lim_{n \to \infty}((1-\frac{1}{n})^{2n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty}(e^{2nln(1-\frac{1}{n})}) =  e^{\lim_{n \to \infty}({2nln(1-\frac{1}{n})})} = e^{2\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ln(1-\frac{1}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}}} \stackrel{L'H}{=} \cdots \stackrel{L'H}{=} e^{2\lim_{n \to \infty}(-\frac{n}{n-1})} = \cdots =e^{-2}=\frac{1}{e^2}$

Comment: Yes, but how exactly do you take the limit? For example, if we let the exponent go to infinity we have $ 0 *  \infty $  and so applying the derivative seems rather logical since it is indeterminate; however, the limit of such an expression does not match -2.

Comment: @KevinPerez Does it result easier to comprehend as I have written it?

Comment: Yes, I see now.

Comment: @KevinPerez Nice!

Answer (score 0):

There is no derivative in this problem. That limit follows straightforwardly from the definition
$$
e = \lim_{ m \to \infty}\left( 1 + \frac{1}{m}\right)^m .
$$

Comment: Without taking definitions as a principle, we have to take the derivative of 2nln(1-1/n) in order to evaluate the limit.